# Displaying lengths in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there a setting in Forge viewer to define how Lengths and other values are displayed?
Below are screenshots for same model, first one is in Revit with Meters set as units for length, second is the same model in Forge Viewer.

[image: Revit Offset]

[image]

Comment: I'm checking that, but as far as I can see, the precision is defined on each property, therefore not configurable on Viewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is under investigation for future improvements, as of August/2017 (v2.16). The **Property** panel uses the `.precision` attribute on each property, see `.getProperties()` method. So if the Revit model is translated with **precision=2** on a property, the Viewer will show 2 decimal places.

You can use a workaround, which is not supported, so use at your own risk :-)

In summary, we can redefine a function from the library.

1. Open the [non-minified version of viewer3d.js](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=2.16)
2. Search for `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.formatValueWithUnits` function definition.
3. Copy to your own .js and add a line at the very beginning:

   ```
   Autodesk.Viewing.Private.formatValueWithUnits = function (value, units, type, precision) {
       precision = 2; // add this line, or something similar

       /// the rest of the original function...
   ```
4. Paste the modified function on your code **after** loading the viewer files.

Remember to always use versioning in your production code. In case of the Viewer releasing a newer version as default, your code still using the hardcoded version. To do so, use `viewer3D.js?v=2.16`.